# Add a constraint to a column on an Oracle table so that only positive values are allowed

Tags: oracle, constraint

I'm not allowed to drop the table, or delete the columns.
The task is to add a constraint to a column possibly by using an ALTER statement so that it disallows any negative numbers. Is this possible?

I tried the following:

```
SQL> alter table SPEND_PLAN_DETAIL_VALUE modify (SP_DETAIL_VALUE_ID CHECK (SP_DETAIL_VALUE_ID > 0));
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [add a constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877) you need to use `add constraint`:

```
alter table SPEND_PLAN_DETAIL_VALUE 
  add constraint check_detailvalue CHECK (SP_DETAIL_VALUE_ID > 0);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ffbaa9c5ff73ae8251534778e6e72ea4)